# Load json file in hive using json serde

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, hive-serde, hiveddl

I am trying to upload json file on hadoop using json serde. I have uploaded jar lib to hadoop but getting error while running hive command

I have uploaded json serde jar file to /apps/hive/warehouse/lib  path.Now, when i am tring to run this command

```
ADD JAR /apps/hive/warehouse/lib/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar;
```

I got this error

> H110 Unable to submit statement. Error while processing statement:
>   /apps/hive/warehouse/lib/json-serde-1.3.7-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
>   does not exist [ERROR_STATUS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your jar is in HDFS location. Use:

```
add jar hdfs:///apps/hive/warehouse/lib/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar;
```

Comment: running this command  add jar hdfs:///apps/hive/warehouse/lib/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar; getting same error H110 Unable to submit statement. Error while processing statement: /apps/hive/warehouse/lib/json-serde-1.3.7-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar does not exist [ERROR_STATUS]

Comment: Try hadoop fs -ls /apps/hive/warehouse/lib/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar and confirm if the file exists

Comment: after running this command i got this on kernel -rw-r--r--   3 admin hdfs      75134 2019-04-10 09:12 /apps/hive/warehouse/lib/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: How are you connecting to hive? Is hive running on the same machine where you did the hadoop fs -ls?

Comment: Try copying the file on to the local file system such as /tmp and try load from there. Let me know if that works

Comment: add jar hdfs:///apps/hive/warehouse/lib/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar;                                                              
converting to local hdfs:///apps/hive/warehouse/lib/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar                                                         
Added [/tmp/6f1a54b9-65c4-4e32-8e87-25d60ef775c6_resources/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar] to class path                                   
Added resources: [hdfs:///apps/hive/warehouse/lib/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar]   successfully added thankyou

Comment: Great to know @user4440416!

Comment: now unable to load json file on hive .. posted on another thread .. if you can help

Comment: @user4440416, please see the response

Answer (score 0):

Try to use URL (add `file//`) before filename:

```
ADD JAR file///apps/hive/warehouse/lib/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar;
```

Also you should be able to add jar from a [repository](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9664) if your Hive is [1.2.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9664) and above.

Comment: how to add jar from repositry?  and in this line of code ADD JAR file///apps/hive/warehouse/lib/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar; what to write instead of file?? which file name?

Comment: Use `http://www.congiu.net/hive-json-serde/1.3.7/cdh5/json-serde-1.3.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar`